# How to scrape dynamic content with BS4 or Selenium (Python)?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape all the file paths in a Github repo from the File Finder page ([example](https://github.com/chrisspen/weka/find/master)).

Beautiful Soup 4 fails to scrape the `<tbody class="js-tree-finder-results js-navigation-container js-active-navigation-container">` element that wraps the list of file paths. I figured this is b/c bs4 can't scrape dynamic content, so I tried waiting for all the elements to load with Selenium:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("https://github.com/chrisspen/weka/find/master")

# Explicitly wait for the element to become present
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((
        By.CSS_SELECTOR, "js-tree-finder-results.js-navigation-container.js-active-navigation-container"
    ))
)

# Pass the found element into the script
items = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].innerHTML;', element)
print(items)
```

But it's still failing to find the element.

What am I doing wrong?

**P.S.**

The file paths can be grabbed easily via the JS console with the following script:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var fileLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("css-truncate-target js-navigation-open js-tree-finder-path"); 
    var files = []; 
    for (var i = 0; i < fileLinks.length; i++) { 
        files.push(fileLinks[i].innerHTML); 
    } 
    return files; 
}
```

**Edit:**

My program requires the use of a headless browser, like PhantomJS.

Comment: Selenium doesn't support multiple class names. If a class includes a space it will be treated as a compound selector, which is selected with By.CSS_SELECTOR.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of PhantomJS can't capture Github content because of Github's Content-Security-Policy setting. This is a known bug and documented [here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/13114). According to that issue page, downgrading to PhantomJS version 1.9.8 is a way around the problem.

Another solution would be to use chromedriver:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
driver.get("https://github.com/chrisspen/weka/find/master")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

element = wait.until(
     EC.presence_of_element_located((
        By.CLASS_NAME, "js-tree-finder-path"
     ))
)
```

Comment: Hm, using the Chrome driver still yields a TimeoutException––it's failing to find the element. And using PhantomJS 1.9.8 on macOS Sierra always segfaults, which is a known and unsolved [issue](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/14558).